# Symfony / Doctrine. FOSUserBundle with custom User Entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-one, findall

I'm using FOSUserBundle together with custom user entities (UserClient, UserCollaborator..). The idea is having OneToOne relations between the FOSUserBundle User and each one of my entities.
My custom User entities are in a separated bundle.

I have the User entity on UserBundle which overrides FOSUserBundle:

```
namespace Acme\Project\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And the UserCollaborator (in a different bundle) which have OneToOne(Unidirectional) relation with User:

```
namespace Acme\Project\ProjectUserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Acme\Project\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserCollaborator
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\Project\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

But in my UserCollaboratorController when I try to list with findAll() it brings just the id of the User, the other attributes of User entity from FOSUserBundle are all null. I tried to implement getters in my Acme\Project\UserBundle\Entity\User calling parent attributes, but it doesn't work (shouldn't need getters as attributes are protected), auto mapping is set to true.

I think it's something related with lazy loading, but I don't know how to handle it (for instance, $userCollaborator->user->getEmail() does not work on my controller)

The exact result for findAll():

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
      protected 'id' => int 1
      private 'name' => string 'Testing' (length=18)
      private 'phone' => string '9999999992' (length=10)
      protected 'user' => 
          public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
          protected 'id' => int 7
          protected 'username' => null
          protected 'usernameCanonical' => null
          protected 'email' => null
          protected 'emailCanonical' => null
          protected 'enabled' => null
          protected 'salt' => null
          protected 'password' => null
          ... everything null
```

Does anyone have already faced this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is correct.

`$user` is set to protected meaning it is only available to itself and extending classes.

If you want to get the user directly using `$userCollaborator->user` you would need to set it to public.

To get the user you would need to use the getter `$userCollaborator->getUser()`.

Comment: sorry, I've forgot to mention in the question, making the attribute public, or keeping it private or protected using getters does not work, when I try: $userCollaborator->getUser(), I get:

"Error: Cannot access empty property in UserCollaborator" which points to my entity on the getter method:


    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->$user;
    }

Comment: Is that a typo or does it actually say `$this->$user`?

Comment: oooh, it was actually $! I can't believe it..

When I fixed the "$" firstly, I still got null properties using $userCollaborator->getUser(), but now doctrine's lazy loading applies! so, using $userCollaborator->getUser()->getEmail() now returns what I expected, just when needed! Thank you so much!